# Find images that are suitable as webpage thumbnail and avoid sprite images

Tags: image, thumbnails, share, sprite, css-sprites

I have all the images of a web page. How can I find out which of them are no sprites?

Sprites are usually many icons on a white or transparent canvas. I could count them and if the count exceeds a certain number, reject the image as sprite image. But I can think of images that may contain many letters/characters that make it look like a sprite image, even though it is a nice thumbnail. How can I distinguish between these two cases or is there a better way to avoid sprite images?

Comment: Firstly, why would you want to *avoid* sprite images? Sprites help to reduce the load time of your page.

Comment: I need a thumbnail of the webpage which is not mine. Sprites are always unsuitable as thumbnails.